# PHP how to extract all *.jpg strings from HTML?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

i have checked many answers but i am still straggling to find a solution.

Case 1:

```
<div id="vsImage" itemprop="image" data-zoom-src="http://example.com/product/760x1013/V373872.jpg"/>
```

Case 2:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/product/760x1013/V373872.jpg"></a>
```

I know i can  easily extract all images from  tag with PHP DOMDocument, but in this case 1 image source is not in  tag.

Maybe the question is, can i somehow get all *.jpg strings from html?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can search for `.jpg` and then seach your way back (index) to the last `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$content = "your HTML content $here";
$matches = NULL;
$pattern = '/(?:http|https|ftp):\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|jpeg)/';
preg_match_all ($pattern, $content, $matches);
```

Comment: It catches only case #2 ;)

Comment: And also is it possible to adapt this regex to match *.jpg string with relative path. (not starting with http...)?

Answer (score 0):

Match all strings between `http` and `.jpg` that doesn't contain a `"`.

```
/http[^\"]+\.jpg/g
```